# Parsing unknown JSON from file and iterate into it

Tags: json, go

I have JSON like this:

```
{
    "store_name": "Barry's Farmer's Market",
    "foods": {
        "apple": "5.91",
        "peach": "1.84",
        "carrot": "6.44",
        "beans": "3.05",
        "orange": "5.75",
        "cucumber": "6.42"
    },
    "store_location": "Corner of Elm Tree Hill and 158th Street"
}
```

And I want to parse it as an unknown JSON using a `map[string]interface{}`:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    var parsed map[string]interface{}

    f, err := ioutil.ReadFile("input.txt")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error: %v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(f, &parsed)
    for k, v := range parsed {
        //fmt.Println(parsed["foods"])
        fmt.Println(k + string(v))
    }

}
```

Considering that "v" doesn't convert to string and that I want to range all the values in "foods", can you help me? I think i'm missing something...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read [the documentation for `json.Unmarshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal), you can see what types it will use, and base your code on that; or use [`fmt.Printf("%T",v)`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) to see what type it is at runtime.

```
err = json.Unmarshal(f, &parsed)
for k, v := range parsed["foods"].(map[string]interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(k, v)
}
```

Working playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/nczV5qA41h

Comment: Nice and perfect. Do you think that using the "reflect" package to find if i have a string or a map[string]interface would be a good idea?

Comment: If you don't know what the structure will be, I would first opt for a [type switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements), and if you need more flexibility, then fall back on reflection. Reflection is generally the worst option, in most languages, including Go.

Comment: I think i'm going to use only _string_ and _map[string]interface_, so type switch is very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could just make a structure which contains a `map[string]string` and iterate over that. https://play.golang.org/p/IVlrTTcrVB

```
type Store struct {
    Name     string            `json:"store_name"`
    Foods    map[string]string `json:"foods"`
    Location string            `json:"store_location"`
}

func main() {
    var store Store
    data := []byte(jsonData)
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &store)
    if err != nil {
       panic(err)
    }
    for k, v := range store.Foods {
       fmt.Println(k + string(v))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[fastjson](https://github.com/valyala/fastjson) may be used for parsing  unknown JSON and iterating into it:

```
var p fastjson.Parser
v, err := p.Parse(input)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// Visit will call the callback for each item in v.foods.
v.GetObject("foods").Visit(func(foodName []byte, foodValue *fastjson.Value) {
    fmt.Printf("%s = %s\n", foodName, foodValue)
})
```